# actionscript 3 - What does export in frame 1 in the symbol properties mean?

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, export, frame, symbols

I have a simple question.
I am using flash professional CS 6 and in the symbols properties panel that you get when you right click a symbol (in my library) and go to properties, there is a check box under Advanced, and it says "Export in frame 1". Now i know what it is to link a symbol to a class, but i don't know what this means. No explanation of this could be found on the adobe site and their reference manual. Please, could you let me know what it means, and why i would/ would not use it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically about giving you the ability to manage load times.

It specifies where it should export the specified symbol and it's class code. You cannot instantiate a instance via code without doing so.

When a .swf movie first loads up, it starts running once everything on frame 1 is loaded. Now suppose you have 50mb of symbols that you have set linkage on to export in frame 1. That means that 50MB will have to load before the user sees anything but a blank stage.

If you don't specify frame 1, the symbols/classes will be exported on whatever frame they first occur in your movie. Again important to note that ANY frame will not actually display until everything that on that frame is loaded.

That's where a preloader comes into the picture.

So what you'd might do in that situation is put only the minimal amount of exports on frame 1 to display your preloader screen as quick as possible. The 50mb of symbols/classes would then be placed on frame 2. So once the 50 MB on frame 2 is loaded, you'd advance to frame 2.

If you specify to export on frame one, you don't even need to put the symbols on the timeline. Only when you don't have that option checked, will you need actually place them on a frame somewhere on the timeline. Just remember that until the frame that contains the content is loaded, you cannot create an instance of that content.

If your game/application is minimal with very little content, just export everything on frame 1 and be done with it. If there is no waiting, there's no need for a preloader.

Comment: So, if i do the preloader way, and have everything loaded during that time, nothing else in the application would need time to load again? Like if i added 100 sprites on the stage at one time, it would not even flinch when it came to displaying them onscreen?

Comment: You simply cannot create an instance of anything until the class/symbol is loaded. It's just about managing WHERE you load your content. Performance of creating 100 sprite instances is a completely different topic.